# File parent string child in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm coding a camera application for *android* and I'm new in `xamrain`. While I'm coding I got this *error* file parent string child for the `CreatDirectiryForPictures` method, if you have seen a *tutorial* that's accessing the camera mobile please link it in the comment!

Any solicitations ?

Thanks.

**MainActivity.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Graphics;
using Java.IO;

namespace Face_orgnaztion
{
    [Activity(Label = "Face_orgnaztion", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


        }
        private void CreateDirectoryForPictures()
        {
            App._dir new File(Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryPictures), "Faceorgnaztion");

        }

        public static class App
        {
            public static File _file;
            public static File _dir;
            public static Bitmap bitmap;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean "App._dir = new File..."?  Otherwise that statement is not valid C#.

Comment: What is the issue? Do you have a stack trace of any sorts?

Comment: Thanks guys , i already solve it !